# The 'onPressed' doesn't work with 'Transform' flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

The 'onPressed' doesn't work with 'Transform' in flutter.

What should I do?

I made an animation to a button (like a fab) to create two buttons with animation but when I click on the two buttons, nothing happens!

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Fab Menu',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  AnimationController animationController;
  Animation degOneTranslationAnimation,degTwoTranslationAnimation,degThreeTranslationAnimation;
  Animation rotationAnimation;


  double getRadiansFromDegree(double degree) {
    double unitRadian = 57.295779513;
    return degree / unitRadian;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this,duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250));
    degOneTranslationAnimation = TweenSequence([
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(tween: Tween<double >(begin: 0.0,end: 1.2), weight: 75.0),
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(tween: Tween<double>(begin: 1.2,end: 1.0), weight: 25.0),
    ]).animate(animationController);
    degTwoTranslationAnimation = TweenSequence([
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(tween: Tween<double >(begin: 0.0,end: 1.4), weight: 55.0),
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(tween: Tween<double>(begin: 1.4,end: 1.0), weight: 45.0),
    ]).animate(animationController);
    degThreeTranslationAnimation = TweenSequence([
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(tween: Tween<double >(begin: 0.0,end: 1.75), weight: 35.0),
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(tween: Tween<double>(begin: 1.75,end: 1.0), weight: 65.0),
    ]).animate(animationController);
    rotationAnimation = Tween<double>(begin: 180.0,end: 0.0).animate(CurvedAnimation(parent: animationController
        , curve: Curves.easeOut));
    super.initState();
    animationController.addListener((){
      setState(() {

      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: size.width,
        height: size.height,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned(
                right: 30,
                bottom: 30,
                child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Transform.translate(
                  offset: Offset.fromDirection(getRadiansFromDegree(270),degOneTranslationAnimation.value * 100),
                  child: Transform(
                    transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(getRadiansFromDegree(rotationAnimation.value))..scale(degOneTranslationAnimation.value),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: CircularButton(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      width: 50,
                      height: 50,
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.add,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      onClick: (){

                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Transform.translate(
                  offset: Offset.fromDirection(getRadiansFromDegree(225),degTwoTranslationAnimation.value * 100),
                  child: Transform(
                    transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(getRadiansFromDegree(rotationAnimation.value))..scale(degTwoTranslationAnimation.value),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: CircularButton(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      width: 50,
                      height: 50,
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.camera_alt,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      onClick: (){

                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Transform.translate(
                  offset: Offset.fromDirection(getRadiansFromDegree(180),degThreeTranslationAnimation.value * 100),
                  child: Transform(
                    transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(getRadiansFromDegree(rotationAnimation.value))..scale(degThreeTranslationAnimation.value),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: CircularButton(
                      color: Colors.orangeAccent,
                      width: 50,
                      height: 50,
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.person,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      onClick: (){

                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Transform(
                  transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(getRadiansFromDegree(rotationAnimation.value)),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: CircularButton(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    width: 60,
                    height: 60,
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.menu,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    onClick: (){
                      if (animationController.isCompleted) {
                        animationController.reverse();
                      } else {
                        animationController.forward();
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                )

              ],
            ))
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}


class CircularButton extends StatelessWidget {

  final double width;
  final double height;
  final Color color;
  final Icon icon;
  final Function onClick;

  CircularButton({this.color, this.width, this.height, this.icon, this.onClick});


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: color,shape: BoxShape.circle),
      width: width,
      height: height,
      child: IconButton(icon: icon,enableFeedback: true, onPressed: onClick),
    );
  }
```

Comment: could you add your relevant code

Comment: https://github.com/letsdoit07/flutter_animated_fab_menu/blob/master/lib/main.dart

Comment: I think the Detection Region remains at its un transformed location.

Comment: @TarekAlabd how did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

as in [this thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19445) on github

> It is intentional that widgets in the overflow area of a stack do not
>   react to gestures and that's unlikely to change. I recommend that
>   people with this (or similar) problems refactor their app to keep all
>   interactable elements within the bounds of a stack.
>
> I do realize that we are not properly documenting this behavior of the
>   stack widget in the API docs. Let's turn this bug into a documentation
>   issue to improve that and properly document the gesture behavior of
>   stack on the class.

in your situation this is the solution
add height about 100 and width about 100 to your Positioned element and
add `alignment: Alignment.bottomRight` to your stack element which is inside the positioned element

```
Positioned(
            height: 200,
              width: 200,
              right: 30,
              bottom: 30,
              child: Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                children: <Widget>[]))
```